# Wordpress Polylang Language Switcher Bug

Tags: wordpress, header, elementor

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQvSj.png)

Hi everyone, my language switcher section in wordpress seems to open like this. I couldn't solve the problem somehow, does anyone have any suggestions?

I tried to fix the header part. But it didn't happen.

Comment: I would be able to help, if I could reproduce the problem.  If this is already online, a link to the site would be perfect.  If it isn't online, if you can put together enough HTML and CSS so that others can set it up for themselves to inspect, that would be great.